# Unable to print JSON from requests

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to pull JSON from this a site but it is not printing the data. I'm not sure if it is the code that's failing or the site. Here is the code:

```
import requests

season = '2016-17'
player_id = 202322
base_url = "http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?CFID=33&CFPARAMS=%s&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameID=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=%s&PlusMinus=N&PlayerPosition=&Rank=N&RookieYear=&Season=%s&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&mode=Advanced&showDetails=0&showShots=1&showZones=0"
shot_chart_url = base_url % (season, player_id, season)

user_agent = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36'
response = requests.get(shot_chart_url, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})

headers = response.json()['resultSets'][0]['headers']

print(headers)
```

Comment: your script hanged when I runned it.

Comment: Your url when pasted with values in browser says `The VsDivision property is required.`

Comment: @Bijoy: When I paste the value in `shot_chart_url` into my browser (which isn't Safari), I get a JSON response as expected.

Comment: The api work in the browser, but it's picky with the request lib, got it to work one time then 400.

Comment: @martineau yeah you are right `shot_char_url` works fine in browser, but get hangs while trying with `requests` and also `urllib2`.

Comment: @Bijoy: I've never got it to work with `requests`, even when trying it several hundreds of times with a `0.25` timeout.

Comment: @martineau bijoy if that works in your browser it means it something with the user agent or cookies.

Answer (score 2):

I could make your script run by changing few things:

```
season = '2016-17'
player_id = 202322
base_url = "http://stats.nba.com/stats/shotchartdetail?CFID=33&CFPARAMS=%s&ContextFilter=&ContextMeasure=FGA&DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameID=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=%s&PlusMinus=N&PlayerPosition=&Rank=N&RookieYear=&Season=%s&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&mode=Advanced&showDetails=0&showShots=1&showZones=0"
shot_chart_url = base_url % (season, player_id, season)
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': user_agent,
    'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
    'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',
    'Referer': 'http://stats.nba.com/events/',
}
response = requests.get(shot_chart_url, headers=headers)
headers = response.json()['resultSets'][0]['headers']

print(headers)
```

I managed a page inside the nba website that use the same api endpoint as yours, after inspecting my requests to the server I did this:

- Added a `Referer` headers - many servers required it(this one is `ASP.NET` and from my experience they do want it.
- Added  2 custom headers of `x-nba-stats`
- Changed the user agent

I think the user agent is the most important one, I feel like they blocking ip+user agents combinations,

**Edit: Just sharing my way of thinking when solving this**
I saw on the comments that this actually works on the browser, knowing how HTTP works this might be related to: cookies/headers/url params. I jump over the original website and search for this endpoint, and indeed it worked for me, I inspect the http request with chrome's DevTools, and mimicked the request with requests :)

Comment: How would a mere mortal know or figure-out what was needed on their own? **That** would be an even better answer in my opinion.

Comment: @martineau edited, I'm mortal as you are, no magic no tricks, I'm doing web crawling for my living but really, it's not rocket science. I hope my explanation was clear :)

Comment: Glad to hear it's not (web)socket science `;-)`, and thanks for disseminating your knowledge and skills!